Kamal deploy can't find application.css
In my Kamal v2 / Propshaft deployed application (Rails 8.0.0) the CSS assets are being compiled (SCSS -> CSS), and pushed to the Kamal container on the remote server, but Rails cannot find them. I'm using Propshaft and no node or other JS tools.
Error log from kamal logs
2024-11-17T17:26:45.976357325Z Information for cause: Propshaft::MissingAssetError (The asset 'application.css' was not found in the load path.):
2024-11-17T17:26:45.976363158Z [d1968adc-03c5-4e53-b2d2-42e19b1b1bc9]
2024-11-17T17:26:45.976368411Z [d1968adc-03c5-4e53-b2d2-42e19b1b1bc9] app/views/layouts/public.html.erb:6

app/views/layouts/public.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>

In the container, the compiled CSS file exists and the contents look OK. (accessed with kamal app exec -i bash)
rails@63cc5d2195a1:/rails/app/assets/builds$ ls
application.css

Gemfile (partial)
gem "dartsass-rails"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "propshaft"

config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.headers = { "cache-control" => "public, max-age=#{1.year.to_i}" }
config.public_file_server.enabled = true

config/deploy.yml
# Bridge fingerprinted assets, like JS and CSS, between versions to avoid
# hitting 404 on in-flight requests. Combines all files from new and old
# version inside the asset_path.
asset_path: /rails/public/assets

Any ideas on how to connect the dots?

I asked ChatGPT (pasted this whole question in) and it gave me the answer. The builds path needs to be added to config/initializers/assets.rb
# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "builds")

(sigh) why are assets still hard in Rails, even when creating the app with  rails new app --css=sass?
I hope this helps someone.
